# jquery animate line height - possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

quick question about the the animate property in jquery, Is it possible to animate

I cant figure out how?
here is my html

```
<nav>
  <a href="">Page 1</a>
  <a href="">Page 2</a>
  <a href="">Page 3</a>
  <a href="">Page 4</a>
  <a href="">Page 5</a>
  <a href="">Page 6</a>
</nav>
<div style="height:9000px;"></div>
```

and javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $('nav').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var $nav = $('nav');
    var $a = $('nav > a');
    if ($('body').scrollTop() > 0) {
        if ($nav.data('size') == 'big') {
            $nav.data('size','small').stop().animate({
                height:'40px',
                line-height:'40px'
            }, 300);
            $a.data('size','small').stop().animate({
                height:'20px'
            }, 300);
        }
    } else {
        if ($nav.data('size') == 'small') {
            $nav.data('size','big').stop().animate({
                height:'100px',
                line-height:'40px'
            }, 300);
            $a.data('size','big').stop().animate({
                height:'40px'
            }, 300);


        }  
    }
});
```

Also is there a way to get the animation for the nav and the a tags to be in sync.

Thanks

ps sorry if its a really basic question - im new to jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/jamesmstone/c7nLB/32/

Comment: It's possible animate you have get the element that you want to move or something and set the correct properties for that. I recommend to read some jQuery animate. http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Comment: Also, you need to quote `line-height` (`'line-height'`), otherwise the `-` in the property-name is interpreted as a mathematical operator, and the `line` and `height` as (undeclared) variables.

Comment: This [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840983/jquery-animate-lineheight-relative-property-gives-weird-result) might be related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, it was your line-height in animate function it should have been 'line-height'

```
$(function(){
   $('nav').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var $nav = $('nav');
    var $a = $('nav > a');
    if ($('body').scrollTop() > 0) {
        if ($nav.data('size') == 'big') {
            $nav.data('size','small').stop().animate({
                height:'40px',
                'line-height':'40px'
            }, 300);
            $a.data('size','small').stop().animate({
                height:'20px'
            }, 300);
        }
    } else {
        if ($nav.data('size') == 'small') {
            $nav.data('size','big').stop().animate({
                height:'100px',
                'line-height':'40px'
            }, 300);
            $a.data('size','big').stop().animate({
                height:'40px'
            }, 300);


        }  
    }
});
```